# :focus won't keep focus, acts like :active

Tags: html, css

so I created a button which has a simple :focus :after tooltip, the thing is that it acts like a :active pseudo-element (it won't stay visible after clicking it)

[GIF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J3xoA.gif)

Here is my SCSS code

```
.copy {
  height: 40px;
  width: 35px;
  right: 25px;
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: transparent;
  border: none;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  opacity: 0.4;
  transition: 0.3s;
  &:hover {
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  &:after {
    content: 'Copied!';
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 2;
    top: -24px;
    left: -7px;
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0.8;
  }
  &:focus:after {
      display: block;
  }
  & svg{
    height: 40px;
    fill: var(--svg_reload);
  }
}
```

Am I missing something obvious ? Thank you

**EDIT:**

After some time trying to figure why it does not work, I gave up on trying to solve it. Instead I have come to make a JavaScript function which creates a span above the clicked button.

```
function tooltip(button){
    var tooltip_exists = document.querySelector(".copy_tooltip")
    if(typeof(tooltip_exists) != 'undefined' && tooltip_exists != null){
        tooltip_exists.remove();
    }
    button.innerHTML += '<span class="copy_tooltip">Copied!<span>';
}
```

Using the onclick="tooltip(this);" HTML property, the function verifies if a span already exists, if one exists it removes it and if not it creates one.

[GIF 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wd8Vs.gif)

Comment: Can you share your HTML as well?

Comment: Sure there you go `<button class="copy" data-clipboard-action="copy" data-clipboard-text="' + value['package'] + '"><svg><use xlink:href="style/svg/copy.svg#copy_svg"></use></svg></button>`

(it is an append)

Comment: I meant can you include it in the question. That would allow people to more easily help you.

Comment: I think you may want `:visited` if you want the css style to retain after the focus has left the element. Otherwise, with `:focus`, it will only retain the focused css style while the element is actively in focus...